# HiltViewModel cant load BaseApplication as Dependency Injection

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I have a legacy project which is completely written in Java. My new project is to update the platform and implement Jetpack Compose and Hilt to be able to work with kotlin and dependency injection.

Jetpack compose: Ive created a kotlin class which handles the creation of composables.

```kotlin
class ComposeCompat(private val app: Activity) {
    fun getListViewComposable(): ComposeView =
        app.findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_list).apply {
            setContent {
                val vm: ListViewModel = viewModel()
                ListView(vm)
            }
        }
}
```

This gets called in the `MainActivity` like this and is able to access the Composable and also the ViewModel:

```java
private final ComposeCompat compose = new ComposeCompat(this);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  compose.getListViewComposable();
}
```

The HiltViewModel looks like this:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ListViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    val state: MutableState<State> = mutableStateOf(State.Loading)

    fun getState() = state.toString()
}
```

The Composable with a viewModel call which works:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ListView(vm: ListViewModel) {
    Log.d("viewModel", "ViewModel starting")
    Log.d("viewModel", vm.getState())
}
```

To this point it works perfectly fine. The problem is if I want to Inject my `BaseApplication`

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ListViewModel
@Inject constructor(private val app: BaseApplication) : ViewModel() {
    val state: MutableState<State> = mutableStateOf(State.Loading)

    fun getState() = state.toString()
}
```

i get this error:

```
Transmitting stack trace: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.compose.list_view.ListViewModel
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
```

I thought that there could be something wrong with the implementation of the `BaseApplication` but that isnt the thing, because when I call the `BaseApplication` in another `HiltViewModel` it works wthout a problem:

The ViewModel:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class DialFragmentViewModel
@Inject constructor(private val app: BaseApplication) : ViewModel() {
    fun onGetApplicationFunction() {
        app.isServiceRunning("com.example.Service")
    }
}
```

It gets called in a Java Fragment like this:

```java
private final DialFragmentViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DialFragmentViewModel.class);
```

Does anyone have an idea whats wrong here? Could it may be that the `ComposeCompat` isnt able to access the `BaseApplication` as a dependency injection?

Comment: did you annotated your ```App``` class with ```@HiltAndroidApp```. this is the first step to initial Dagger-Hilt.

Comment: @ChiragThummar yes, otherwise it would not work for `DialFragmentViewModel` aswell

Comment: I think you have not declared in  ```Singleton``` Module.

Comment: @ChiragThummar What singleton? for the `BaseApplication`? why do you think that?

Comment: Check out this code. It might help. https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6b7m.png

Comment: Did you declared any module that provides the instance of your `BaseApplication`? If not, then Hilt will be unable to instantiate your `ListViewModel` class as it doesn't know how to get that instance. So you have to provide instance of your `BaseApplication` through Hilt module.